# Understanding anchoring in Hype Processing

Tags: processing

I am trying understand how anchoring works in HYPE library for Processing 3.

I built a very small example to illustrate my question. In the following code, I expected the triangles not to intercept each other:

```
HPath d1,d2;

void setup(){
    size(600,600);
    H.init(this).background(#202020);
    smooth();
    float u=100;


        d1 = new HPath();
        d1
            .triangle( H.EQUILATERAL, H.TOP )
            .noStroke()
            .fill(#FF0000,100)
            .size( 1*u )
            .loc( 0, 0 )
            .anchorAt(H.TOP)
        ;
        H.add(d1);
        d2 = new HPath();
        d2
            .triangle( H.EQUILATERAL, H.BOTTOM )
            .noStroke()
            .fill(#00FF00,100)
            .size( 1*u )
            .loc( u/2,0 )
            .anchorAt(H.TOP)
        ;
        H.add(d2);


    H.drawStage();
}
```

Isn't **size()** the side of the triangle? If so, if I am setting the size to **u** and start drawing a new triangle at position (**u/2**,0), why are they overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

It seems all down what you consider to be the size of triangle (ie circumscribed circle in HYPE library methinks).

```
HPath d1, d2;

void setup() {
    size(600, 600);
    H.init(this).background(#202020);
    smooth();
    float u = 100 * sqrt(3);
    d1 = new HPath();
    d1
    .triangle( H.EQUILATERAL, H.TOP )
    .noStroke()
    .fill(#FF0000, 100)
    .size( u / sqrt(3))
    .anchorAt(H.TOP)
    .loc( 0, 0 )
    ;
    H.add(d1);
    d2 = new HPath();
    d2
    .triangle( H.EQUILATERAL, H.BOTTOM )
    .noStroke()
    .fill(#00FF00, 100)
    .size( u / sqrt(3))
    .anchorAt(H.TOP)
    .loc( u * 1 / 3, 0 )
    ;
    H.add(d2);
    H.drawStage();
}
```